# in which segment, zero initialised static variables will be stored?

Tags: c

When I declare a static variable like

```
static int x = 0;
```

in which section of data segment, it is stored? I know all uninitialized data variables are first initialized to '0' by kernel and stored in BSS. But if I initialize the global or static variables to '0' myself where these variables will be stored (in BSS or initialized Data segment)?

Comment: I've used some compilers where it went to BSS and some where it went to Data. BSS seems more sensible. Are you asking about a particular compiler/linker ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb : Thanks Mat. I am perticularly interested in gcc compilers.

Comment: "I know that" followed by something completely false...

Comment: @KerrekSB : what you found as false?

Comment: Why not just try it? Run a test program under GDB.